# unboundLocalError: local variable 'arm' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python

Hi everyone I'm a beginner in python and I'm trying to make my own text rpg game. I have made a method for the hero to shop in the store but for some reason I'm getting this error every time I reach the shop :

> nboundLocalError: local variable 'arm' referenced before assignment

Can someone explain to me what this means and how I can fix it? thanks

```
 def shop():
        dagger = ('Dagger', 0, 5)
        sword = ('Sword', 0, 10)
        leather_hide = ('Leather Hide', 5, 0)

        if IsShopLocked == True:
            print("The shop is locked!\nPlease go back and continue your adventure!")
        else:
            print()
            print("Welcome to the Larkville shop! What would you like to buy?\n1. Weapons\n2. armor\n3. Go back")
            selection = int(input("Enter a value: "))

        if selection == 1:

                print("Weapons shop")
                print("1. Bronze Dagger: $7\n2. Bronze Sword: $50 3.Rusty Sword $60")
                wpnselection= int(input("Enter a value: "))

        elif wpnselection == 1:

                if hero.ac<20:
                    print("You donthave enough gold to buy this yet ")
                main()
        else:


                    hero.damage += 10
                    hero.ac -= 20
                    print("strength increased to: {}".format(hero.damage))
                    main()

        if wpnselection == 2:
                if hero.ac<50:
                    print("You dont have enough gold to buy this yet...")
                    main()
                else:


                    hero.damage += 16
                    hero.ac -= 50
                    print("strength increased to: {}".format(hero.damage))
                    main()


        elif wpnselection == 3:
               if hero.ac<60:
                    print("You dont have enough gold to buy this yet...")
                    main()
               else:


                    hero.damage += 28
                    hero.ac -= 60
                    print("strength increased to: {}".format(hero.damage))
                    main()

        elif selection == 2:

                print ("Armor Shop")
                print ("1. Leather hide 20$\n2. warmogs armor 30$")
                arm = int(input("enter a value: "))

        if arm == 1:

                if hero.ac<20:
                    print("You dont have enough gold!")
                main()
        else:

                hero.hp += 20
                hero.ac -= 20
                print("Health increased to: {}".format(hero.health))

        if arm == 2:

                    if hero.ac<30:
                     print("You dont have enough gold!")
        main()
        if hero.ac>30:
                    leather_hide = Item('Leather Hide', 5, 0)
                    IsLeatherHideEquipped = True
                    hero.hp += 20
                    hero.ac -= 20
                    print("Health increased to: {}".format(hero.health))


        elif selection == 3:
           main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that when you do:

```
if arm == 1:
    # code
if arm == 2:
    # code
```

you have not defined what arm is.. you only define `arm` in this line:

```
arm = int(input("enter a value: "))
```

Which is in an inner scope of the `elif` - which means that if it doesn't reach that point then `arm` is indeed a local variable that was not assigned before doing anything with it.

Maybe what you meant to do is that these `if arm == 1: ...` in the scode of the `elif` above I can't tell but I think you should see how you can change your code to contain less spagetti code.. deviding into functions and maybe classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared variable `arm` inside the `elif`(inner scope) and you are trying to use that variable out of that scope. Here, Same thing is happening with another variable `selection`.

If control would not reach up to that conditions, your variables would be undefined.

You can first declare these variable with `None`

```
def shop():
    dagger = ('Dagger', 0, 5)
    sword = ('Sword', 0, 10)
    leather_hide = ('Leather Hide', 5, 0)
    selection=None
    arm=None
    #rest of the code.
```