# Unbound local variable

Tags: python

I get this error when i try running this i find it weird since i dont have 2 functions so im not sure why i tried using global and not fixed:

Traceback:
   in 
   in remove_smallest
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lowest' referenced before assignment

```
   def remove_smallest(numbers):
        for i in range(0,len(numbers)-1):
            lowest=0
            if((numbers[i]<numbers[i+1]) and (numbers[i]<numbers[lowest])):
                lowest=i
        del numbers[lowest]
        return numbers
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unboundLocalError: local variable 'arm' referenced before assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198356/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-arm-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 3):

Define `lowest` before the `for` loop.

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    lowest=0
    for i in range(0,len(numbers)-1):
        if((numbers[i]<numbers[i+1]) and (numbers[i]<numbers[lowest])):
            lowest=i
    del numbers[lowest]
    return numbers
```